# Multi dimensional list Python (beginner)

Tags: python

I want to create a multi dimensional list where in the program the user is ask to either input a seat number or a price and then replace them with `0`.

This is what I have so far:

```
board = [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
         10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
         10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
         10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10,10,
         10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10,10,
         10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,10,10,
         20,20,30,30,40,40,30,30,20,20,
         20,30,30,40,50,50,40,30,30,20,
         30,40,50,50,50,50,50,50,40,30,]

def show():
    print(board [0], board[1], board[2], board[3], board[4], board[5], board[6], board[7], board[8], board[9])
    print(board [10], board[11], board[12], board[13], board[14], board[15], board[16], board[17], board[18], board[19])
    print(board [20], board[21], board[22], board[23], board[24], board[25], board[26], board[27], board[28], board[29])
    print(board [30], board[31], board[32], board[33], board[34], board[35], board[36], board[37], board[38], board[39])
    print(board [40], board[41], board[42], board[43], board[44], board[45], board[46], board[47], board[48], board[49])
    print(board [50], board[51], board[52], board[53], board[54], board[55], board[56], board[57], board[58], board[59])
    print(board [60], board[61], board[62], board[63], board[64], board[65], board[66], board[67], board[68], board[69])  
    print(board [70], board[71], board[72], board[73], board[74], board[75], board[76], board[77], board[78], board[79])
    print(board [80], board[81], board[82], board[83], board[84], board[85], board[86], board[87], board[88], board[89])


while True:
    seat = int(input("Please enter a seat or price"))

    if board[seat] != "0" :
       board[seat] =  "0"
    else:
        print("This seat is laready sold")


    show()
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to replace the index value with zero when a price is given for instance if the user input is price "40" instead of replacing the index value 40 I want to replace the price number "40".

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Btw, this isn't related to your question, but you might consider using something like print(board[0:10]) and potentially use that with a for-loop. That way you can abstract your code and also save yourself some time!

Comment: As @qwertyuip9 says, use something like `for i in range(0, 90, 10): print(*board[i:i+10])`.

Comment: Also, your code's `board` contains integers, but you're comparing them to strings in that loop.

Comment: As you said in my deleted answer's comments, if the user choose `40`, then what should be changed? Can you give an example of the expect output?

Comment: the first available seat with a price of 40 would be replace with 0 meaning that is not available  for example if the user inputs 40 this will happen  board = [10,10,20,40,40,40] board = [10,10,20,0,40,40]

Comment: How is the program supposed to know whether the "40" is a seat or a price?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Hint: the user will have to _tell_ the program.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about the problem. A user enters a number that could be either a seat, or a price.

Let's say we have 100 seats. The user gives us 50. If we have any seats that are priced less than or equal to 100, how do we know what 50 means? Is it 50th seat, or 50 dollars? The value is ambiguous without context.  So I suggest you ask for some.

Instead of asking for just a number, maybe try asking for a number and what it is for. So if the user wants the 50th seat, they can say `seat 50`. And now we know what they mean when they say 50. This does mean you will have to implement that yourself however.

As a side note, you do mention that you want a multi dimensional list. Right now your list is flat, meaning it is single dimensional. You can see that because no elements of your list (`[...]`) are lists themselves.

An example of a multi dimensional list would be `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`. This is a 3x3 multi dimensional list.